# java readObject() in multithread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets, objectinputstream

I'm making a chat and file transfer app, I have one method for updating every incoming information about the file like this:

```
public class ClientController {
    private void updateFileChat(){
        new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            while(true){
                 //other codes
                 Message message = (Message)objectInputStream.readObject();
                 //other codes
          }
        }
        }.start();
}
```

But I've created a method for an inner class of the above class,it extends MouseAdapter class, when user clicks the information, it will download the correspond file:

```
private class DownloadFileListener extends MouseAdapter{

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            //other codes
            long size = ObjectInputStream.readLong();
            //other codes
            }
     }
```

And I think they've conflicted. What should I do to execute the thread that run the listener first each time I click the info of the file. I'm new to thread and I've stucked this for 2 days, please help me :(

Comment: Simple answer: don't. It doesn't make sense to assume in two independent threads that one of them is going to receive a `long` next and the other is going to receive an object. You can't know what is being sent next, and you can't know which of your threads is going to issue its read first. You need to reconsider this from the ground up.

Comment: What should I do :( I have to implement a method that update the chat data when another client upload the file and other method to download the file when I click the name of that file in the chat field like facebook. Please help me :(

Comment: Usually, there's a thread that reads incoming messages, inspects them to see what type they are, and then dispatches them to the proper object for an action. So if you have a String and a Long message, then you'll dispatch the first to the chat window or somesuch, and the second to somewhere else.

Comment: @Tassos Bassoukos Thank you! It worked! XD